# Is it possible/recommended to install TortoiseHg if (a newer) mercurial is already installed?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have searched the docs and it is still unclear to me if I can install TortoiseHG on a machine where mercurial is already installed. In particular I [find in the FAQs](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.5/faq.html) that the installer bundles Mercurial. But, on the other hand, to build from source requires (obviously) to [hg clone the repository](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/thg).

My problem is that I installed the latest release of Mercurial (which, as of Nov 2012, is 2.4) while all the currently available THG releases refer to previous versions. For instance,

```
2012-10-01: TortoiseHg 2.5.1 (with Mercurial 2.3.2) released
```

as can [be seen in the news](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) as of Nov 2012.

What is the best course of action? I have currently installed hg 2.4 and I have already created a local repository, which I am handling via the command line.
It is possible that I missed the relevant information online: please point it out to me if that is the case.

Comment: Why do you need hg 2.4? TortoiseHg is updated regularly, in a matter of days or weeks, it'll be bundled with the newer version. At least it has been so. TortoiseHg uses mercurial's python library internally, I don't know if it can be configured to use an external `hg`.

Comment: It's not that I need it specifically. It's just that the latest release which was suggested by the project page was 2.4. Now that the "damage" is done, what's the best way to proceed? Are 2.4 repositories backward compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best course of action is to just keep things as they are. According to Mercurial 2.4's [upgrade notes](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UpgradeNotes#A2.4:_minor_changes), only bookmark handling has been incompatibly changed since 2.3. So, the repositories should still be compatible between versions.

In future upgrades, you'd better wait for TortoiseHg to catch on the latest release of Mercurial. Unless you need a security update or a critical fix, there are few reasons to upgrade so diligently. Moreover, if you use the GUI regularly, there's even less need to upgrade Mercurial separately.

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for the comment. If I understand you are against using a tortoiseHG version which doesn't bundle 2.4 EVEN if the repository should be compatible (I don't even know what bookmarks are in the context of mercurial, so I shouldn't have created them :-) )? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not against. You may use thg with the older bundled hg, as far as I can tell. I advise you to not do it after you upgrade to thg with hg 2.4. That is, I advise you to keep both the standalone hg and thg's hg synchronized, unless you have a really good reason to update the standalone version any sooner.

Comment: @Francesco, I reread your question, and I see that you have installed Mercurial 2.4 and you don't have any TortoiseHg. I was assuming you had TortoiseHg already installed. So, I scratch the part where I said "keep things as they are", and I say "go ahead, install the current TortoiseHg, but remember to upgrade it as soon as it bundles Mercurial 2.4".

Answer (score 1):

The Mercurial crew is extremely diligent about being backward compatible; Take a look at the [release notes](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_2.4_.282012-11-1.29) to see if there's anything in 2.4 that might make a difference for a Mercurial 2.3.x client to a 2.4 repository. The TortoiseHg crew has been quite good about keeping up with newer releases of Mercurial, so you won't have to wait too long to see a new release of TortoiseHg based on Mercurial 2.4.

Comment: Thanks @smooth : does that explicitly mean that it is possible to access without corrupting it a 2.4 hg repo with a tortoiseHG version which bundles 2.3?

Comment: As @paulo-maderia has noted, only the way that Mercurial handles bookmarks may have changed to be incompatible with 2.3. For all other operations, your client running 2.3 will not have a problem talking to a 2.4 repository. That said, it just seems like a good idea to be consistent unless you have a really compelling reason to be on different versions. Since TortoiseHg comprises a version of Mercurial and a set of tools that are compatible, it's a good idea to abide by the release cycle of TortoiseHg, especially if you are using its shell overlays and workbench for regular work.